# Submitting AddHoc iPhone App Binaries to Apple App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store, adhoc

Hey I have taken over from a developer who submitted Add Hoc Build Binaries to the app store instead of creating a new binary with an app store development provisioning profile.

Can anyone tell me what will happen to these apps?

So far they they are fine, approved and selling with the added benefit that we are able to test the actual binary we upload to itunes connect, which if you compile using an app store only provisioning profile, you can't.

Am I missing something here? Why do apple instruct us to use an app store only provisioning profile, when add hoc ones work fine?

Answer (score 0):

I question the assertion that an ad hoc build was submitted.  I've done this myself by accident, and it gets rejected at the upload stage.

> we are able to test the actual binary we upload to itunes connect

Have you tried this yourself and seen it work?  Even if it were to work once, I wouldn't make decisions on the assumption that it will continue to work in the future.

Comment: i agree here, i doubt the  op was able to use an ad hoc profile for distribution, itunes connect most likely woudlnt even accept the binary signed with that profile

Comment: Also, on the statement "we are able to test the actual binary".  There really shouldn't be any difference.  Anyway, code signing is a separate step, so if you really, really wanted to....

Comment: Yes defo, it let me upload a binary made with my addhoc provisioning profile, I always thought it would be rejected and obviously has in the past, well this is the only way I know of to test the submitted binary so seams ok to keep doing I guess...

Comment: I accidentally did this last week and Chris is right: ad hoc builds are accepted by Apple for App Store distribution.